# How to Select Only Alphanumeric characters from a string in Datastage?

Tags: internationalization, alphanumeric, datastage

I am facing a problem with my data, in my data other than alphanumeric characters are there in a column field, where for ***EX*** in Name column: **Ravicￌhandr￢an (￢ￌ￮`)** like these many characters are there. I need a result like Ravichandran. How can I achieve this? Is there any way to remove in transformer stage.

I tried Convert function in Transformer stage, but problem in using Convert, I am not sure about these unknown characters, I have shown above is just example.

My Requirement is, other than alphanumeric must be removed. And the Balance string should be the same.

How can I get this done?

Answer (score 0):

The following Convert function can be used in Transformer stage to remove any kind of unknown/special characters from the column.

```
       **Convert(Convert('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 ','', Column_Name1),'',Column_Name1)
```

Ex : Convert(Convert('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 ','', to_txm.SourceCode),'',to_txm.SourceCode)**